# How can I store data in an external database, the data is from WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

1. How can I save form records from a form plugin in an external database? For example, how can I store form records from JetFrom Builder in an external database? A plugin is preferred, but if I have to code I will.
2. How can I generally store things from WordPress in external databases?
3. Should I use the WordPress built-in database for users or an external database for users?

Thank you very much for your answers.